# ES6 Style Import in Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I would like to import an external module from node_modules in node using typescript using the import syntax. I've added the type definitions to my project so I can call `install()` without typescript returning errors (I know I can do an `any` cast require but I would obviously like to keep everything typed if possible).

```
/// <reference path="typings/source-map-support/source-map-support.d.ts" />

import * as sourceMapSupport from 'source-map-support';
sourceMapSupport.install();
```

However when my code is output it returns the following:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/source-map-support/source-map-support.d.ts" />
//# sourceMappingURL=server.js.map
```

Could someone explain to me why it doesn't output a require in the resulting js file? Also I'm compiling to ES6 as I need a access to the async & await keywords - my tsconfig.json is as follows.

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
   "target": "es6",
   "sourceMap": true,
   "outFile": "build/server.js"
},
   "exclude": [
       "node_modules",
       "typings"
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could someone explain to me why it doesn't output a require in the resulting js file

Because you are using `outFile` in tsconfig `"outFile": "build/server.js"`. Don't use `outFile` if you are using a module format. That is a job a bundler e.g. webpack.

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
   "target": "es6",
   "sourceMap": true,
   "module": "commonjs"
},
   "exclude": [
       "node_modules",
       "typings"
   ]
}
```

## PS

Note : There are edge cases here e.g. systemjs / amd support outFile. But that's not most likely not relevant here.